# search for a button inside an accordion with part of its text, Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I'm learning robot framework since a couple of weeks, and I have the next situation while making a robot with a real case:

I have a value of the id of a company, and with it, I need to locate the button with that info which is inside of an accordion on the website, the accordion button list is totally variable and can have one or various items

for context, the part of the site is like this:

```
<div class="accordion ui fluid"><div class="item" style="background-color: white; margin: 1rem 0px; border-radius: 10px;"><div class="title accordion-title"><i aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown icon"></i>Accordion 1</div><div class="content" style="padding: 1rem; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);"><div class="persona-btns"><div><button class="ui primary button">Accordion1 op1</button><button class="ui primary button">Accordion1 op2</button></div></div></div></div><div class="item" style="background-color: white; margin: 1rem 0px; border-radius: 10px;"><div class="active title accordion-title"><i aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown icon"></i>Accordion2</div><div class="content active" style="padding: 1rem; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);"><div><button class="ui basic button" style="padding: 0px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px; text-align: inherit;">*id number of a company* *variable text(name of a company)*</button></div></div></div></div>
```

I tried with a

```
Click Button    //button[.//text()=*id value*]
```

but in that case, doesn't find anything, and just comes with an error

and the other option, is to use a Get WebElements Keyword, with the container of the buttons, and that lists the webelements but without a direct way to make it match the text value:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3932a0dd61c3018f5ede7ca31ea475b1", element="59b4ad4d-3410-4e95-b1e5-3d02e07d1894")>]
```

so I need to find a way make the framework identify the element with the text, or in the WebElements option, to get the text of the html and get the data to make it clickable with the Click Button Keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `id value` is not the exactly text content value of any text node inside that button.
So, instead of this `//button[.//text()=*id value*]` please try this XPath expression

```
//button[contains(.,'*id value*')]
```

So, the entire command line will be

```
Click Button    //button[contains(.,'*id value*')]
```